# IntelliJ IDEA mac os keymap ^ not working

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I am running

IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1
Build #IC-145.597, built on March 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_40-release-b132 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

and i use the **Mac OS X** keymaps.

While most of the shortcuts work as expected some of them are still bound to the OS's functions, rather than the IDE's actions.

For example when i type **Control(^)+Space** instead of code completion it changes the OS X's input language. Additionally, when i pre **Control(^) + Right/Left Arrow (->|<-)** instead of navigating between the open tabs, nothing happens.

I think for some reason the Control(^) is bound to Mac's actions.

Is there any way i can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ctrl+Space works fine for me, but the other doesn't. *"Is there any way i can fix this?"* Yes, assign another shortcut. It's annoying, I know, but I wouldn't bother it that much. Would be wasted time and nerves :D.

Comment: Shortcuts on the OS have precedence over Intellij. So just disable the ones in the SO.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` and disable the system shortcuts that interfere. When they are disabled there, IntelliJ IDEA can receive them.

Comment: The asker didn't ask to disable the system shortcuts, they exist for a reason. When you type in mixed languages a lot, you need a shortcut to switch between the languages; switching them with the mouse is insane.